# Steam wont open on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: steam

in console I am displayed this.

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
```

No matter how long I wait it does not finish.

Comment: what graphics card are you using? are the drivers to it installed?

Comment: I had the same issue. It worked after a reboot. No idea why...